# custom url for custom post type search

Tags: wordpress, url-routing

I have custom post type Events..

URL is www.mysite.com/events/eventname, these events will have people joining them which I plan to solve by building custom DB table and placing event id and user id inside.. Now what I want and don't know even what to type in google is how to make and rule so when somebody what to see whoi s going to event that he can type URL www.mysite.com/events/eventname/users and the specific template will be pulled which will query that custom DB and show what users are attending..

I will figure out query code just need help how to make that custom url to load that query ?  Is this possible within Wordpress ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider using php's `$_GET` or `$_POST` to do this instead. It will work fine in WordPress too.

Warning untested code ahead.

### $_GET request

Sending a `$_GET` request using a url looks something like this:

```
www.mysite.com/events/?eventname=myeventname&users=true
```

You can then use an if statement in your php on the events page to load data depending on whether these variables are included in the url. Something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['eventname']) && isset($_GET['users']) && $_GET['eventname'] == 'myeventname' && $_GET['users'] == true){
    //Spit out all the users here
}else{
    //Continue as if nothing happened
}
```

### $_POST Request

Post request is another way of sending data from one page to another (or sending data to itself) and if you go with this method you won't be making any changes to the url. The most common way to send a `$_POST` request is with a form. In this case it might be a form with some invisible inputs that will hold our data. Something like:

```
<form action="www.mysite.com/events/" method="post"> <!-- Submitting form to self -->
    <input name="eventname" type="hidden" value="myeventname"></input>
    <input name="users "type="hidden" value="true"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="See who's going"></input>
</form>
```

And then retrieve the data when the form is submitted:

```
if(isset($_POST['eventname']) && isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['eventname'] == 'myeventname' && $_POST['users'] == true){
    //Spit out all the users here
}else{
    //Continue as if nothing happened
}
```

Finally, just on the custom DB table, it might be a good idea to use WordPress users rather than building out another table. You will then be able to make use of all of those handy functions that WordPress comes with.

Best of luck!